Automating Tenant ID Assignment in Single Table Multitenancy with Spring Data R2DBC
Is it possible to set a default value for a column in a SELECT or UPDATE query using R2DBC?
In my scenario, multiple tenants share the same database, schema, and tables, with the only distinction being a tenant_id column in each table. I want to avoid manually setting this column in every query.
I’ve seen some solutions for this using JPA + Hibernate, but that's not applicable in my case. I also found a similar question from 2021, so I’m wondering if there's been any progress on this front since then. Has this feature been implemented?
